# Wacom Bamboo: Remove keydown alert boxes

Tags: alert, bamboo

I've been trying to google this for hours, and have gone through the settings at least three times. After searching Superuser a few times as well, I still cannot find an answer. This is driving me crazy trying to work around the stupid little box.The issue is, any time you hold down a function key (CTRL, SHIFT, ALT etc) a little alert hoverbox pops up telling you bluntly which key you are holding down. Well I know what key it is, I'm holding the damned thing down for a reason. This is ridiculous in Photoshop while trying to draw as a little box is hiding the next area that I'm trying to draw on, causing much CTRL+Z'ing.

Is there a way to turn this stupid thing off? How do artists cope with that damned thing anyway?